# jQuery Selector Intersection get meta with property="article:tag" and content="tag"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to check whether an article has a specific tag set in the meta data. Thus I'm looking for the intersection of to jQuery selectors meaning the element what fullfilles both [property="article:tag"] and [content="mytag"]:

I tried so far:

```
if( $('[property="article:tag"]').has('[content="mytag"]') ) ...
if( $('[property="article:tag"].[content="mytag"]') ) ...
```

Neither is working.

However

```
if( $('meta.[property="article:tag"]') ) ...
```

is working.

Is there any intelligent jQuery command which can select this out of the box?

Thx, I really appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 3):

Try to merge those selectors and use `length` property,

```
if($('meta[property="article:tag"][content="mytag"]').length) {

}
```

Or use [`.is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($('meta[property="article:tag"]').is('[content="mytag"]')) {

}
```